# Why we need fine tune word embedding in recurrent neural networks?

Tags: nlp, theano, recurrent-neural-network

In the theano's tutorial about [RNN](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/rnnslu.html), at the final part it mentioned that

> We keep the word embeddings on the unit sphere by normalizing them after each update:

```
self.normalize = theano.function(inputs=[],
                                  updates={self.emb:
                                              self.emb /
                                              T.sqrt((self.emb**2)
                                              .sum(axis=1))
                                              .dimshuffle(0, 'x')})
                                              .sum(axis=1))
                                              .dimshuffle(0, 'x')})
```

I searched online and only find the paper [Investigation of Recurrent-Neural-Network Architectures and Learning Methods for Spoken Language Understanding](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/pointeurs/RNNSpokenLanguage2013.pdf) mentioned it is fine-tuning word embedding in Chapter 3.5.1.

I don't understand why we can fine tune word embedding.     `self.emb` is the imput of this RNN model, right? How could we change the input value?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem, and this is my understanding:

Actually `self.emb` is not purely the input of the RNN, it also likes a part of parameters(or vectors in word2vec) which is trained to fit the words in [ATIS](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/rnnslu.html#dataset).

When we treat it as the parameters, the fine-tune is reasonable.

But when we treat it as the input, normalization becomes reasonable.

In addtion, I read the paper you mentioned and I think fine-tuning doesn't contain the normalization because fine-tuning is a type of supervised learning, but the normalization is just a processing of data.